# Displaying Results of innerjoin by choice of quantity

Tags: php, mysql, row, inner-join

I'm trying to innerjoin 2 tables. Table 1 contains ID of user online only. Tables 2 contains ID's of all users and their names.

I wish to echo a list of the users that are online by joining Table 1 with Table 2 by their ID's then displaying the name, however my results don't seem correct.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online INNER JOIN base ON online.ID = base.id");
echo "<table>
<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The echo'd result is displaying around 15 members of the 60+ that are in the online table. I do not wish to show all results, but I do want to be able to show them in a random order (so the lowest ID isnt always first) and display only 5 of the users in the list. This way I can choose how many it displays depending on the further development of my website.

All help is appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing what you want. Best would be hybrid approach in which you just get as many items, as you want to show on the page by limiting the results in mysql. Thus a very less load on the database (in case database grows gradually)

**Simple Offset approach using DISTINCT**

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID, USER_NAME FROM online INNER JOIN base ON online.ID = base.id limit 5 OFFSET $value;
```

where $value changes based on your logic. You can use the limit keyword without using offset as well.

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID, USER_NAME FROM online INNER JOIN base ON online.ID = base.id limit 5 OFFSET RAND();
```

RAND() will also give you the desired results until and unless it stays in your results total count range.

**Offset using Group by approach**

```
SELECT * FROM online INNER JOIN base ON online.ID = base.id GROUP BY UserName limit 5 OFFSET $value;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm very grateful. However, trying what you have showed me, the first option listed 5 results (as I wanted) however, it seemd to duplicate the names so there is 2, for example its displaying; User#1, User#1, User#2, User#2, User#3

Comment: Thats due to the nature of the join. You will need to use the distinct keyword on the username/id columns. Another way is to group by results which isnt very efficient one. I have updated the queries and added example for group by as well.

Comment: Ah, it seems you are my savior! My results are now displaying perfectly! thank you soooooo much :)

Comment: Also, it was using the DISTINCT username method that solved it

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad to know that it solved your problem.